# Como fazer sub-query de forma correta no Oracle?

Tags: oracle, virtualbox

Eu preciso fazer uma sub-query de uma tabela para encontrar todos os empregados que trabalham em um mesmo departamento que faz parte de São Paulo, mas não estou conseguindo. Ou seja, preciso selecionar das três tabelas, `departments`, `employees` e `locations` para saber de quais locais os empregados trabalham. E eu preciso selecionar `state_province` da tabela `locations` enquanto selecionando o `first_name`, `departments_id` e `job_id` da tabela `employees`.

Eu tenho as seguintes tabelas :

**Tabela departamento**

```
DEPARTMENTS

department_id
department_name
location_id
```

**Tabela locais**

```
LOCATIONS

location_id
street_address
postal_code
city
state_province
country_id
```

**Tabela empregados**

```
EMPLOYEES

employee_id
first_name
last_name
email
phone_number
hire_date
job_id
department_id
```

Com o meu atual código ele não funciona, esta mais ou menos assim :

```
SELECT firt_name, department_id, job_id 
FROM locations 
WHERE state_province = (SELECT * 
                        FROM locations 
                        WHERE state_province = 'Sao Paulo');
```

Ele começa a dar erro na parte do `WHERE` já que `state_province` somente pertence á tabela `LOCATIONS` e não tem como eu acessar os atributos dela. Como eu posso fazer esta sub-query de forma correta ?

Sou novo nesta parte de select aninhado com outro select, então me desculpem os erros grotescos.

Comment: substitui o `*` da subquery por `state_province`, senão vc estaria igualando um campo com um registro inteiro, ja que `locations` tem mais que uma coluna

Comment: Obrigado, mas o problema agora é de que eu não consigo selecionar os atributos da tabela departamento, enquanto fazendo o aninhamento com o outro select. Eu precisaria mostrar o o nome do funcionário por exemplo, que está na tabela departamentos, enquanto selecionando state_province, da tabela locations. Como posso fazer isto ?

Comment: opa, desculpa pelo comentário atravessado no reflexo, é o sono  e a pressa, eu deveria ter ficado quieto, haha =( estou escrevendo uma resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É sempre bom pensar duas vezes antes de utilizar uma subquery para resolver um problema de SQL, principalmente se for algo que manipula grandes volumes de dados ou que é executado muitas vezes, pois essas queries tem que ser guardadas na memória para comparação posterior, piorando a performance da aplicação.

No caso apresentado, considerando que um `EMPLOYEE` está relacionado a um `DEPARTMENT` e este a uma `LOCATION`, você precisa expressar esse relacionamento na sua query e acredito que não seja necessário utilizar subqueries. Há duas formas básicas de se fazer isso com uma só query, uma definindo cláusulas `JOIN` e outra utilizando testes na cláusula `WHERE` que provocam a criação de um `INNER JOIN` implícito.

Em ambos os casos todas as três tabelas devem estar envolvidas e os campos devem ser qualificados pelos nomes das tabelas a que pertencem, para evitar ambiguidade. É possível definir `aliases` para as tabelas, se necessário, para reduzir a quantidade de texto na query, mas manterei os nomes por extenso para maior claridade.

---

**Usando a clásula `WHERE`**:

```
SELECT 
  employees.first_name, 
  employees.department_id, 
  employees.job_id 
FROM 
  employees,
  locations,
  departments
WHERE 
  departments.location_id = locations.location_id and
  employees.department_id = departments.department_id and 
  locations.state_province = 'sao paulo';
```

Esse tipo de query, na minha opinião, apresenta menor "verbosidade" do que usando `JOIN` explícito, facilitando a leitura. O uso de `WHERE` para esse tipo de finalidade só se faz possível por se tratar de relacionamento simples, em que todas as tabelas possuem dados para cruzar,  de forma que as igualdades expressadas resultam em um `INNER JOIN` implícito.

---

**Usando `INNER JOIN`**:

Como disse acima, prefiro o uso do `WHERE` nesses casos por achar mais interessante colocar todas as regras em um só lugar, mas acredito que o "mais correto" seja definir os relacionamentos entre tabelas no `FROM`, utilizando cláusulas `JOIN`. Além de ser o uso canônico do SQL, a principal vantagem é a possibilidade de expressar relacionamentos mais complexos.

Segue o mesmo relacionamento da query anterior, agora expressado com dois `INNER JOIN`. Tomei a liberdade de alterar os campos pedidos em `SELECT` e o filtro em `WHERE` para demonstrar que as colunas de todas as tabelas são acessíveis (note, isso é possível em qualquer dos dois métodos de join aqui expostos).

```
SELECT 
  employees.first_name, 
  employees.department_id, 
  employees.job_id ,
  departments.department_name,
  locations.street_address
FROM 
  employees inner join departments on employees.department_id = departments.department_id
            inner join locations on departments.location_id = locations.location_id 
WHERE 
  departments.department_name = 'ti';
```

A definição explícita de `JOIN` possibilita mais rápida compreensão visual dos relacionamentos estabelecidos pela query. Há também outros tipos de `JOIN` que dão mais controle sobre qual das tabelas tem precedência na recuperação dos dados, algo que não é de todo possível através do uso de `WHERE`.

---

**Encadeando subqueries**:

Se por algum motivo for necessário que o relacionamento entre as tabelas não seja expresso na cláusula `FROM` nem na `WHERE` conforme acima, ele pode ser reproduzido através de queries encadeadas (também chamadas de "queries derivadas") na cláusula `SELECT`.

Embora se obtenha, para todos os efeitos, um "desdobramento" do uso de `WHERE` demonstrado anteriormente, este método é um tanto limitado nos campos que se pode buscar, visto que apenas as colunas da query "de fora" serão retornadas:

```
select * from employees where department_id in (
  select department_id from departments where location_id = (
    select location_id from locations where state_province = 'sao paulo'
  )
);
```

Note que para que seja possível a comparação de um campo com uma query em cláusula `WHERE`, é necessário que essa query retorne também apenas um campo do mesmo tipo. Caso a subquery retorne mais de um *registro* e seja necessário buscar por todos, mude o operador do `WHERE` de `=` para `in`.

---

- SQL Fiddle demonstrando as queries acima utilizando alguns dados
  montados sob o modelo informado na pergunta:
  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49b40/6
- Para mais informações sobre uso do `JOIN`:
  http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/

Comment: Olá amigo, muito obrigado pela resposta cheia de informações, mas no caso mesmo não sendo viável eu preciso utilizar sub-query. E no caso, eu preciso selecionar state_province da tabela locations enquanto selecionando o first_name, departments_id e job_id das tabela employees.

Comment: Inclusive o query acima, sem ser do JOIN, não me retorna nada mesmo sendo que há na tabela locations, um empregado de São Paulo.

Comment: @Monteiro por "precisar usar a subquery" você quer dizer que não pode alterar o from e o where da query principal? quanto a nao funcionar os dados de que preenchi no exemplo estão todos em caixa baixa, mas vi pela pergunta que sua base contém "Sao Paulo" capitalizado. Chegou a verificar isso?

Comment: SIm eu cheguei a verificar. Eu tenho que selecionar as três tabelas, e encontrar todos os empregados que trabalhem na cidade São Paulo. E somente usando sub-query, sem join.

Comment: @Monteiro o encadeamento de queries que incluí na resposta te ajuda?

Comment: Estranho, parece que está todo certo o encadeamento mas mesmo assim ainda não retorna a query mostrando a cidade São Paulo e os empregados relacionados á ela.

Comment: @Monteiro ele não te retorna nada, como você comentou tambem no caso do uso de `WHERE` acima? Quando você falou que o `JOIN` funciona, testou tambem com o campo `state_province = 'Sao Paulo'`? Se não, tenta só para ver se também dá problema. Pode ser que o registro de Sao Paulo tenha algo que faça com que  banco não o encontre, como por exemplo estar cercado de espaços. Um teste também seria usar o like, em vez de igualdade: `where state_province like '%Sao Paulo%'`...

Comment: Não funcionou do mesmo jeito. Então, eu tenho somente um funcionário que trabalha na cidade de São Paulo. Mas quando eu faço o SELECT aninhado ele me retorna todos os funcionários de todas cidades. Está mais ou menos assim : SELECT first_name, department_id,job_id FROM employees, locations WHERE state_province = (SELECT state_province FROM locations WHERE state_province = 'Sao Paulo'); E ele acaba retornando todos funcionários ao invés de somente o funcionário que trabalhe de fato em São Paulo. Como posso arrumar isto?

Comment: Isso acontece porque você colocou duas tabelas no `WHERE`. Na prática você está pegando todos os registros de `EMPLOYEES` e juntando com todos os registros de `LOCATIONS` que tem `state_province = 'Sao Paulo'`. Não dá pra pular etapas desse jeito, seu modelo de dados tem 3 relacionamentos encadeados, employees > departments > locations. Olha a comparação nesse fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49b40/18

Comment: Exatamente, por isto estou tendo problemas. Não estou conseguindo puxar somente do registro EMPLOYEES, por que ele junta da parte dos registros de LOCATIONS. Na sua comparação do fiddle deu o que eu queria que estivesse rodando no Oracle. Como posso resolver isto de vez? Tenho que ir por partes para pegar todos os 3 relacionamentos e chegar ao resultado somente depois?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67987/discussion-between-monteiro-and-nunks-lol).